# How to redirect with Status Code to another URL in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I would like to redirect the user to another URL but along with a status code.

The following code does the redirection, but the Status code is always 302.

```
public ActionResult RedirectWithStatusCode(string redirectionUrl, int statusCode)
{
     try
     {
           Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
           return Redirect(redirectionUrl);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           Response.StatusCode = 404;
           //log exception
           return new EmptyResult();
     }            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectPermanent()` for Status code `301` and `Redirect()` for Status code `302`.

There are variants like `RedirectToAction()`, `RedirectToActionPermanent()`, `RedirectToRoute()` and `RedirectToRoutePermanent()` that follows the same principle.

EDIT:

Answering your question, if you want to manipulate the response in a lower level, try the below:

```
public void RedirectWithStatusCode(string redirectionUrl, int statusCode)
{
    try
    {
        Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        Response.Headers["Location"] = redirectionUrl;
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        //log exception
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Test URL: /redirectwithstatuscode?statuscode=308&redirectionurl=http://google.com

[image]

**Warning**: You may need to make sure the URL passed belongs to your domain, otherwise you may expose your website to redirection attacks.

Comment: But is there a way where we can configure the status code or send them as arguments as shown in question,

Comment: It is an ActionResult method and not void. So, what should be the return type.

Comment: You are terminating the response in the body of the function, so no need to return anything. Void works, but I would recommend sticking to the builtin methods Redirect and RedirectPermanent if that works for you.